# How can I change colour of text based on its value when a page initially loads?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing up a program in spring and one aspect is a crime rating feature. Based on user input, API querying and some calculations I can come up with a rating out of 10. Like so (Garda Station is Police Station in Irish)

[image]

I thought a cool feture would be if the colour of the numbers changed i.e. low score gets green, high score gets red etc. I'm printing this information from a Controller class in my Spring application. I've tried the following method:

I added an id to the `<b>` tag to pass the value into a javascript variable like so:

```
<c:forEach var="o" items="${gardaStationList}">
        <tr>
            <td width="10%" height="50"><h2>Based on <b><c:out value="${o.gardaStation_name}" /></b> and their statistics
                                            the rating for this area is:  <b id = "rating"><c:out value="${o.crime_rating}" /></b></h2></td>  

         </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

And when the page loads I made it run the following javascript function, but I have a feeling it's executing this before the rating loads so it's not working?

```
window.onload = function() {
  var rating = document.getElementById('rating').value;
  if (rating < 4) {
    document.getElementById("rating").style.color = "#45FD00";
  } else if (rating > 4 && rating < 6) {
    document.getElementById("rating").style.color = "#E6E6E6";
  } else if (rating > 6) {
    document.getElementById("rating").style.color = "#ff0000";
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can run the function after the text loads or am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but only form field elements have a `.value` property. Regular elements have a `.textContent` property.

Instead of `b`, use `span`, which is more suited to containing some inline content. For styling something to be bold, use CSS.

Next, give each element that will contain the data you need a common CSS class name to group them together instead of using unique `id`s on the various elements. This makes it very easy to gather them all up or add more later without having to change your JavaScript.

Also, use CSS classes instead of creating dynamic inline styles because classes are more flexible and allow you to use the `element.classList` object, which makes it easy to add, remove and toggle classes.

```js
// When all the HTML has been parsed and is available...
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Get all the ratings into an array
  var ratings = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.rating'));
  
  // Loop over the array
  ratings.forEach(function(r){
    // Get the text that is inside the element
    var val = +r.textContent; // The prepended + converts the text to a number

    // Just add the appropriate pre-made CSS class to the element
    // depending on its text content.
    if(val < 4 ){
      r.classList.add("low");
    } else if(val >= 4 && val <= 6){
      r.classList.add("medium");
    } else if(val > 6){
      r.classList.add("high");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rating { font-weight:bold; }
.low { color:#45FD00; }
.medium { color:#880; }
.high { color:#ff0000; }
td { width:10%; height:50px; }
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
     <td><h2>Based on statistics the rating for this area is:  <span class="rating">10.04</span></h2></td>  
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><h2>Based on statistics the rating for this area is:  <span class="rating">5.4</span></h2></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>
     <td><h2>Based on statistics the rating for this area is:  <span class="rating">0.4</span></h2></td>  
   </tr>    
</table>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Looks much better now thank you Scott

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var rating = Number(document.getElementById('rating').textContent);
```

The `.value` you're using will only work (return something besides undefined) for an element that has a `value` attribute. Input tags and other form related tags often have this: `<input type="text" name="fname" value="John">`

Comment: Only use `innerHTML` when you're deliberately using or inserting HTML markup (which can have security and encoding problems). When you're setting or retrieving text values, use `textContent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the `textContent` of the element first. `value` only works for `input`s and `textarea`s.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var rating = document.getElementById('rating').textContent;
```

You can also keep your code DRY by selecting `#rating` only once, rather than many times:

```
window.onload = function() {
  const ratingElement = document.getElementById('rating');
  const ratingNumber = Number(ratingElement.value);
  if (rating < 4) {
    ratingElement.style.color = "#45FD00";
  } else if (rating > 4 && rating < 6) {
    ratingElement.style.color = "#E6E6E6";
  } else if (rating > 6) {
    ratingElement.style.color = "#ff0000";
  }
}
```

Comment: *`value` only works for `input`s and `textarea`s* **And, `select` and `button`.**